# Creating tz aware pandas timestamp objects from an integer

Tags: numpy, pandas, datetime64

I have a integer that is the number of microseconds after the unix epoch. (in GMT)

How can I convert  1349863207154117 using astype to a pandas.Timestamp("2012-10-10T06:00:07.154117", tz=¨UTC¨)?  The documentation on astype is not very thorough.  I have tried the following.

```
x = 1349863207154117
dt64 = np.int64(x).astype("M8[us]")
print dt64
```

returns:

```
np.datetime64("2012-10-10T06:00:07.154117-0400")
```

2. if I only want seconds, this works:

```py
time = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x / 1e6)), tz=¨UTC¨)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Pandas: Epoch timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#epoch-timestamps) covers this.

```py
In [2]: pd.to_datetime(1349863207154117,unit='us')
Out[2]: Timestamp('2012-10-10 10:00:07.154117')
```

- If you want this in a local timezone

```py
In [6]: pd.to_datetime(1349863207154117,unit='us').tz_localize('US/Eastern')
Out[6]: Timestamp('2012-10-10 10:00:07.154117-0400', tz='US/Eastern')
```

- If your time is in UTC, but you want it in another tz.

```py
In [9]: pd.to_datetime(1349863207154117,unit='us').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
Out[9]: Timestamp('2012-10-10 06:00:07.154117-0400', tz='US/Eastern')
```

- Or this

```py
In [10]: pd.to_datetime(1349863207154117,unit='us',utc=True).tz_convert('US/Eastern')
Out[10]: Timestamp('2012-10-10 06:00:07.154117-0400', tz='US/Eastern')
```

Comment: in theory epoch timestamps should be UTC/GMT. but you never know. as that is the problem, no meta-data to actually tell you.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked into the timestamp. Its in a crazy format.